# Host TFS on Azure

Tags: azure, team-foundation-server, entra-id

I am trying to set up a distributed instance of TFS on 2 Azure VMs and I am having issues getting the main TFS Server to see the TFS DB Server. It is complaining about needing to be on an Active Directory. This is quite new to me so I have been trying a lot just to get it to work.

I created two Virtual Machines both Windows Server 2012 R2 on Azure using the Resource Manager. I set up one of those servers to work as an AD machine by configuring it through the Server Management Application, I set up a domain, but could not get the other VM to join to this domain, even though I was able to ping the IP addresses from each machine.

I then tried setting up the AD machine as a DNS machine as well but trhen I wasn't able to remote on to the machine anymore so had to delete it and start again as I couldn't get the powershell azure to reset the password.

I would appreciate some insight into this, even if you would be able to let me know if this is possible.

My biggest issue just now is understand Azure and how the Active Directory works on Azure.

Thanks.

Comment: There are many valid reasons to run TFS in the cloud and you may have already considered and discounted it, but I just wanted to check that you are aware that MS offer a PaaS TFS service called Visual Studio Team Services that has many of the features of on prem TFS without needing to manage IaaS servers.

Comment: That would be a business decision which I don't have the authority to make at the moment. It could be a solution for us but it would take time to set a business case for it. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of @Alex Belotserkovskiy I was able to determine what the issues were that was stopping the TFS Server to be able to contact the TFS DB Server. It was a mix of:

- Not having DB Set up as Domain Controller with Active Directory installed.
- Not having an entry in the hosts file pointing to the Domain at the DC IP.
- Not having the addition DNS Servers set in the properties of the ethernet card.

After I done all this, I was able to join both machines to my own domain and get them to see each other.

Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Good! Could you mark the answer then? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little old, [but still working guidance from ALM Rangers on how to deploy the TFS to Azure IaaS](http://vsarplanningguide.codeplex.com/downloads/get/842516). There are some nuances like it would be helpful to put your VMs into one Virtual Network to give them the continuous address space, etc.

And yes, it is absolutely possible. Just make sure that you follow the guidances and do not miss settings.

UPD: as per chat, it was the issue with the DNS resolution and domain join.

Comment: Ok thanks, I already had this document but it was a bit overwhelming, I'll look into it again. Thanks

Comment: @stuartmclark i am almost sure that the issue can be related to the virtual network (that you was not able to join the domain). Basically, when i deployed such a configuration, the steps were as 1) create virtual network 2) put your vms into that vn so they will be in the same network and domain works 3) join the domain 4) install everything needed. Virtual network here is the network boundary that will give you the experience like a local one of installation.

Comment: Hi Alex, yeah that sounds right, I have created two VMs on the same virtual network but I don't know how to get them to join a domain, even if it is only a domain between those two machines. It does not need to be an extension of my company domain.

Comment: @stuartmclark may we chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111623/azuretfs